Extremely slow telemetry queries in Thingsboard after switching from Cassandra to Timescale
Today we attempted a switch from Cassandra to Timescale as our data store for Thingsboard. Everything seems to work OK except for the Telemetry Controllers endpoints:

We are able to query the telemetry data without issues if we query it directly in the database
We are able to query all other Controllers (device, relations etc.) via the Thingsboard API without issues

The problem only arises if we query data using the Telemetry Controllers endpoints, in which case the query becomes extremely slow and we start to get timeouts.
Does someone know what might be causing this?
I can provide additional information about our setup if need be.

Can you please paste some query examples that are very slow? The output of the EXPLAIN ANALYZE can help you to understand where you're missing indices or some parts that can be optimized.
I'd also recommend you to enable `pg_stat_statements extensions and track the queries performance to make it easy to profile your issue.
